# Why we don't use keyword 'function' in Angular components?

Tags: angular

Inside the ts file,

```ts
export class ComponentName{
   methodName (para1,para2) {
     //code here
   }
}
```

this is considered correct but when I add the keyword function to the method, the code doesn't compile and give errors saying it only expects methods, accessors, constructors and properties.

Comment: Because it's not a function, it's a method. Same reason you can't `let` or `const` in a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having problems understanding ECMAScript 6. Angular uses TypeScript, which is based on ECMAScript 6.

> Traditional JavaScript uses functions and prototype-based inheritance
>   to build up reusable components, but this may feel a bit awkward to
>   programmers more comfortable with an "object-oriented approach", where
>   classes inherit functionality and objects are built from these
>   classes. Starting with ECMAScript 2015, also known as ECMAScript 6,
>   JavaScript programmers will be able to build their applications using
>   this object-oriented class-based approach. In TypeScript, we allow
>   developers to use these techniques now, and compile them down to
>   JavaScript that works across all major browsers and platforms, without
>   having to wait for the next version of JavaScript.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> class Greeter {
>     greeting: string;
>     constructor(message: string) {
>         this.greeting = message;
>     }
>     greet() {
>         return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
>     }
> }
>
> let greeter = new Greeter("world");
> ```
>
> The syntax should look familiar if you’ve used C# or Java before. We
>   declare a new class Greeter. This class has three members: a property
>   called greeting, a constructor, and a method greet.

[[Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)]

Answer (score 1):

As mention @virsha, it's not about Angular it's about ECMAScript 6 [method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name.

```js
const obj = {
  foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
};

console.log(obj.foo());
// expected output: "bar"
```

The shorthand syntax is similar to the [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) syntax introduced in ES5.

Given the following code:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: function() {
    // ...
  },
  bar: function() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

You are now able to shorten this to:

```js
const obj = {
  foo() {
    // ...
  },
  bar() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In Typescript documentation this refers to [Class methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#methods).

> A function property on a class is called a *method*. Methods can use all the same type annotations as functions and constructors:

```js
class Point {
  x = 10;
  y = 10;

  scale(n: number): void {
    this.x *= n;
    this.y *= n;
  }
}
```

Other than the standard type annotations, TypeScript doesn’t add anything else new to methods.